# Difference between /mnt/local and /mnt/internal?

Tags: file-system

I have a WonderMedia 8650 based tablet running Android 4.0.3.  The File Manager app shows the internal flash file system as "/mnt/local", I can also see a "/mnt/internal" filesystem that's identical.  Running adb shell and using the mount and df commands I can see this:-

```
1|root@android:/ # mount
…
/dev/fuse on /mnt/local type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other)
/dev/block/vold/31:13 on /mnt/internal type yaffs2 (rw,relatime)

root@android:/ # df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
…
/dev/fuse                 5.9G    119.0M      5.8G   2% /mnt/local
/dev/block/vold/31:13
                          5.9G    119.0M      5.8G   2% /mnt/internal
```

To me it looks like /mnt/local is a "fuse" loopback filesystem sitting on top of /mnt/internal, but I have no idea what the fuse layer give me.  Does it add something like the virtual directories we see in the Microsoft Windows "Libraries" view?

My main concern at the moment is that I've had reports that files written to /mnt/internal have disappeared.  Is this something that might happen, and if so should I make sure we only ever use /mnt/local and leave /mnt/internal well alone?

Thanks for any advice.